# Применение playbook поочередно к хостам с помощью vars_prompt

Tags: ansible

Есть задача с помощью vars_prompt задать в файл sudoers на каждый хост инвентаря имя в соответствии с названием группы OU из ad. На каждый хост префикс группы соответствует названию хоста(разные соотв.)

```yaml
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars_prompt:
    - name: group_name
      promt: whats the name a group?
      private: no
  tasks:
    - name: add group to the sudo
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/sudoers
        line: "%{{group_name}} ALL=(ALL) ALL"
      loop: "{{ group_name }}"
```

Тут все ясно, завис как решить вопрос применения отдельного к каждому хосту. Циклом? Команды на исполнения плейбука поочередно к хостам не нашел. Может знает, буду признателен.